# Set height and width for popup window in variable (syntax issue probably)

Tags: javascript

I got the basics of my javascript to function with help I got here on Stackoverflow. I see a bit of room for improvement on what I have now though. A lack of Javascript knowledge keeps me stuck unfortunately.

I'm trying to set arguments such as width, height, toolbar, status for a popup window in a variable. I tried every way I could find both here and via Google to get the syntax right but whatever I try it doesn't seem to work.

See below in Function1 what I ended up with (Function2 still has the hardcoded parameters that I'm trying to put in the variable called windowSpecs).

```js
var windowSpecs   = "\'toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745\'"; 
 
var function1Name  = "test_function_1";
var function1Url  = "https://www.google.com"; 
var function1Class  = ".test_function_class1"; 

var function2Name  = "test_function_2";
var function2Url  = "https://www.cnn.com"; 
var function2Class  = ".test_function_class2"; 



// Function 1 
window[function1Name] = function () {
    window.open(function1Url, windowSpecs,"_blank",);
}

jQuery(function1Class).click(function() { 
    window[function1Name]();
});


// Function 2 
window[function2Name] = function () {
    window.open(function2Url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}

jQuery(function2Class).click(function() { 
    window[function2Name]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any pointers that could help me figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Nick Parsons !

Comment: you need to maintain the sequence of arguments, options is 3rd argument, so make '_blank ' as second, 'windowspecs' as 3rd

Comment: That did it, thanks! (would never have thought to google anything about the order of things.. lesson learned!)

Comment: Just make sure nobody downvotes your question will result in loss of rep points,